# Can I cache Apple Maps?

Tags: ios7, mapkit

So here is the scenario, 
I am working on this piece where direction tab holding the map and there is a pin on address and callout bubble is automatically been shown as view appears. if you click button get driving directions it take user to apple maps for direction.

As this map is static I was thinking instead of download every time on when view appears, Is it possible to Cache the map, let say 1 sq Kilomerters or the area which is shown in the view.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apple caches the map for you. 
If the user will not load other map data, it will be in the cache.

You cannot force your part of the map to stay in the cache.

Edit:
I tried it with disabling wlan, so the device cannot load the map data anymore from net. It looks like it is loading, but this is more a building up ob the map data.
it shows the map data previously loaded, but cannot load new one.

Comment: but on my phone app loads it every time I run the app ? Am I observing it wrong ?

Comment: look my edit. it looks like it os loading, but it is not

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to control the caching in MapKit. Check out the [Mapbox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk) or [MBXMapKit](http://mapbox.com/mbxmapkit).